# PHP - Searching for string and outputting into new string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Let's say I put the following into a textbox:

```
1|[Guangzhou Evergrande](//www.gzevergrandefc.com/)|6|5-1-0|+15|**16**
2|[Shandong Luneng](//www.lunengsports.com/)|7|5-1-1|+7|**16**
3|[Qingdao Jonoon](//www.zhongnengfc.com/)|7|4-3-0|+4|**15**
4|[Beijing Guoan](//www.fcguoan.com/)|7|3-3-1|+2|**12**
```

when I press enter, it would take what's between the `[` and `]` and `(` and `)` and put it into new lines like this:

`if ($name == "NAME_HERE") $name = "[".$name."](URL_HERE)";`

I tried doing `preg_match` and using this pattern: `$pattern = '/^[/';` and `$pattern_end = '/^]/';` for the name -- jsut to test -- but I cannot get it to work....

Here is what I have so far:

```
$string = '1|[Guangzhou Evergrande](//www.gzevergrandefc.com/)|6|5-1-0|+15|**16**';
$pattern =  '/\[(.*?\)].*?\((.*?)\)/';
$replacement = 'if ($name == "{1}") $name = "[".$name."]({2})";';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: `(.*?\)` needs to be `(.*?)` since that bracket is for the subpattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern should be

```
 '/\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)/'
```

because [ ] and ( ) are special characters. Use preg_match_all() function

when you use preg_match_all you can put () for submatches(subpattern)

example

```
<?php

$string = '1|[Guangzhou Evergrande](//www.gzevergrandefc.com/)|6|5-1-0|+15|**16**';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/(<([\w]+)[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/\\2>)/", $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Comment: I edited my question to include progress: I got `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 21 ... fix.php on line 5`

Comment: I got it using preg_array match and such! Tahanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I don't fully understand what you are doing here, but, I see a data structure that can be exploded without a hassle. For example:

```
function get_football( $text ) {
    $r = array();
    $t = explode("\n", $text );
    foreach( $t as $l ) {
        $n = explode("|", $l);
        $r[] = $n;
    }
    return( $r );
}
```

This will get you a nicely structured set of data that you can foreach() through and further process.  If the original text is stored inside $variable0, `print_r( get_football( $variable0 ) );` will show a nice structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => [Guangzhou Evergrande](//www.gzevergrandefc.com/)
            [2] => 6
            [3] => 5-1-0
            [4] => +15
            [5] => **16**
        )

    [1] => Array
```

Of course, that $n[1] name can be broken down further in the loop.  Anyhow, thereafter, you can loop through whatever menu you're building with a foreach() loop instead of hardcoding menu choices. Just something to consider.